# $string is not showing up in php search

Tags: php, ajax, string, search

Just got some help with my ajax/php search but now my issue is that the link is not even showing up on the search page. The echo results are showing up but the $string isn't.

Thanks for the help.

```
//echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$string = '';

if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)!=0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<p> <b>'.$row['title'].'</b> '.$row['post_ID'].'</p>'   ;
     $string .= "<p><a href='set-detail.php?recordID=".$row['post_ID']."'>".$row['title']."</a></p>";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
}
```

Comment: Is the `$string` variable echoed anywhere?

Comment: You shouldn't print user input without escaping it first.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092524/having-trouble-with-php-and-ajax-search-function where I've already given the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you echo `$string`. If you put the echo command in there for `$string` it may begin to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing $string anywhere.

Are you sure you meant to use $string, and not just `echo` it, like you have with the line above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `echo $string;` or simple echo the line as it is generated if you are calling this inline i.e.

`echo "<p><a href='set-detail.php?recordID=".$row['post_ID']."'>".$row['title']."</a></p>";`

Answer (score 0):

You do not echo the string above.

After your loop you need to echo it.

```
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)!=0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo '<p> <b>'.$row['title'].'</b> '.$row['post_ID'].'</p>'   ;
 $string .= "<p><a href='set-detail.php?recordID=".$row['post_ID']."'>".$row['title']."</a></p>";
}

echo $string;
```